# Laravel - three relationships

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I have the following structure

```
Orders  
 - id  
 - users_id  
 - orderPaid (can be 1 or 0) 




OrdersItems  
 - id  
 - order_id  
 - events_id  
 - qty 


events  
- id  
- name  
- (and others)
```

**Relationships**
One Order hasMany Orderitems. One Orderitem belongsTo Order.
One Event hasMany Orderitems. One Orderitem belongsTo Event.

**What I need to do is:**
Get all the Events with ALL paid(!) qty's. So if i have 2 orders with two items each (total 4) but just one order is paid, qty should **show = 2** instead of 4

Code so far:

```
$events = Main::with(['clients','events.orderitems'])->where('id', $id)->first();
foreach($events->events as $events) {
    $events->orderscount = count($events->orderitems);
}
```

gives me successfully the total qty, but I just need the qty if orderPaid = 1

How can I do that? Every help is every appreciated

Comment: Rephrase what you want to achieve. `count(orderitems)` is not the same as sum of the orderitems qty field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Eloquent [eager load constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) (this will add a subquery):

```
$events = Main::with(['clients', 'events.orderitems' => function($query) {
    $query->whereIn('order_id', function($query) {
        $query->select('id')->from('orders')->where('orderPaid', 1);
    });
}])->where('id', $id)->first();
```